# How to use LINQ to find a sum?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this structure:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> _storage =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

key: Firmware(string): key: Device(string) : value CountOfUsers (int)

I need to get the total of users for each device, but I really don't know how to do it with LINQ. Already tried a lot of variants. Please, help!

For now, I just use a whole function for it

```
private XlsRow2 GetTotalPerDevice(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> storage)
    {
        XlsRow2 totalPerDeviceRow = new XlsRow2();
        totalPerDeviceRow._Name = "Grand Total";
        totalPerDeviceRow.UseBorders = true;
        foreach (var deviceModel in _allDeviceModels)
        {
            foreach (var firmware in storage)
            {
                foreach (var device in firmware.Value)
                {
                    var countOfUsers = 0;
                    if (deviceModel == device.Key)
                    {
                        countOfUsers += device.Value;

                        if (!_totalsPerDevice.ContainsKey(deviceModel))
                        {
                            _totalsPerDevice.Add(deviceModel, countOfUsers);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _totalsPerDevice[deviceModel] += countOfUsers;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var deviceModel in _allDeviceModels)
        {
            if (_totalsPerDevice.ContainsKey(deviceModel))
            {
                totalPerDeviceRow._AddColumn(_totalsPerDevice.First(k => k.Key == deviceModel.ToString()).Value.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                totalPerDeviceRow._AddColumn("");
            }
        }
        return totalPerDeviceRow;
    }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Something like this for example?

```
var result = _storage.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x => new { Device = x.Key, Total = x.Sum(y => y.Value) });
```

Answer (score 12):

Since the keys for the data that you would like to aggregate is in the second-level dictionary, a good first step would be to dump all key-value pairs from inner dictionaries into a flat sequence. After that all you need is to aggregate the counts, like this:

```
var res = _storage
    .SelectMany(d => d.Value)
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Comment: Once again the advice that not allways the best answer has the highest score but simply the one that already has many votes. Sorry. bro.

Answer (score 11):

A Dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` which means you can use LINQ on it. In this case you have a dictionary of dictionaries and need to group by the second level key. To do that, you need to flatten the dictionaries, something that can be done with `SelectMany`

```
_storage.Selectmany(pair=>pair.Value);
```

Once you have the leaf-level entries, you can group by their keys:

```
_storage.Selectmany(pair=>pair.Value)
        .GroupBy(leaf=>leaf.Key);
```

And calculate the sum per group:

```
var totals=_storage.SelectMany(pair=>pair.Value)
                   .GroupBy(leaf=>leaf.Key)
                   .Select(grp=>new {
                                        Device = grp.Key,
                                        TotalUsers =grp.Sum(leaf=>leaf.Value)
                                    });
```

The equivalent query is rather cleaner:

```
var totals2 = from frm in _storage
              from dev in frm.Value
              group dev by dev.Key into grp
              select new {
                           Device = grp.Key,
                           Total=grp.Sum(leaf=>leaf.Value)
                         };
```

Given the following dictionary:

```
var _storage = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> {
    ["Frm1"]=new Dictionary<string, int> { 
                    ["Device1"]=4,
                    ["Device2"]=5
                },
    ["Frm2"]=new Dictionary<string, int> { 
                    ["Device1"]=41,
                    ["Device3"]=5
                }                    
};
```

Both queries return the same values

```
foreach(var total in totals)
{
   Console.WriteLine ($"{total.Device} = {total.Total}");
}
------------------
Device1 = 45
Device2 = 5
Device3 = 5
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this like:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> _storage = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
Dictionary<string, int> x = new Dictionary<string, int>();
x.Add("x", 2);
x.Add("z", 2);
x.Add("y", 2);
_storage.Add("x", x);
_storage.Add("z", x);
_storage.Add("y", x);

 var b = _storage.SelectMany(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value)
         .GroupBy(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key)
         .ToDictionary(valuePairs => valuePairs.Key, grouping => grouping.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

result will be like:
[image]